# How to install DBD::DB2 on Windows (For nagios db2check)

Tags: perl, db2, nagios

I am trying to install DBD::DB2 perl module for Windows Server. I have installed Strawberry Perl, however none of the repositories I have tried worked, including this one:

```
ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm64/DBD-DB2.ppd
```

It gives the error: `it is not intended for this build`

I want to run the check_db2_health from a Centos Nagios Server and I need this on the Windows Server to be able to do so. [Link here](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/DB2/check_db2_health/details)

Is there a way I can install the DBD::DB2 and DBI modules?

Comment: What version of perl are you using? Is your OS 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Try this: `ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/DBD-DB2.ppd`

Comment: Sorry, The full error is: "this is not intended for this build of Perl." Also, I tried the ppm (not ppm64), same result. When I do a perl -v it shows: v5.24.0

Comment: You could use CPAN to install the module then. Just run `cpan DBD::DB2` from terminal.

Comment: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\DBD\DB2\DB2.xs.dll'
  IBMTORDB2/DBD-DB2-1.85.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'DBD::DB2'.

Comment: Running in shell as administrator did not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

See my answer

I've found a work around for this, just insert this the following files:

- Constants/Constants.xs
- DB2.h

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65591186/1750851